# Почему появляется ошибка если отправлять боту эмодзи?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Написал бота, работает правильно, но при вводе смайлика в консоли появляется вот такая ошибка

```
> No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\os\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "C:\Users\os\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "C:\Users\os\tb\bot.py", line 16, in on_message
    text2 = text[ :: -1 ]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Ниже программа бота

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

ii = 1

def on_start( update, context ):
  global ii
  ii = 1
  chat = update.effective_chat
  context.bot.send_message( chat_id = chat.id, text = \
    "Привет, Андрей, как у тебя дела, мой любимый ребёнок ? :)" )

def on_message( update, context ):
  global ii
  chat = update.effective_chat
  text = update.message.text
  text2 = text[ :: -1 ]
  if ii == 1 :
    ii = 2
    context.bot.send_message( chat_id=chat.id, text = \
      "Ты моя буся сладкая. Поиграем в зеркало, ты мне что-то напиши, а я это переверну" )
  else :
    context.bot.send_message( chat_id=chat.id, text = text2 )

print( "Бот запущен. Нажмите Ctrl+C для завершения" )
token = ''
updater = Updater( token, use_context = True )
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler( CommandHandler( "start", on_start ) )
dispatcher.add_handler( MessageHandler( Filters.all, on_message ) )
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Похоже, эмодзи не в `update.message.text` попал, посмотрите сами в `print(update.message)`. Кст, а с `text = update.effective_message.text` такая же проблема?

Comment: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html `text (str, optional)` — не у всех сообщений есть текст.

Comment: @gil9red видимо дело в том что не все сообщения возвращают текст, как написал Alexey Ten. Надо как-то проверить что text имеет текстовый тип, т.е. text is str или Type( text ), точно не знаю

Comment: @alex, просто `if text: ` это проверит что не None, и что текст есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял в чём была проблема. Проблема в том, что *телеграм не всегда возвращает для бота текст*. Например, если ввести какой-то анимированный смайлик, которых очень много в телеграмме, то в качесте текста возвращается *отсутствие значения* или `None`. Значит просто добавляем проверку на значение `None` ( или так `text == None` )

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

ii = 1

def on_start( update, context ):
  global ii
  ii = 1
  chat = update.effective_chat
  context.bot.send_message( chat_id = chat.id, text = \
    "Привет, Андрей, как у тебя дела, мой любимый ребёнок ? :)" )

def on_message( update, context ):
  global ii
  chat = update.effective_chat
  text = update.message.text

  if text == None :  # Я сам себе предлагаю вот такое решение
    text = ':)'        # Проверяем на отсутствие значения
                     # ( в случае ввода эмодзи или гифки )

  text2 = text[ :: -1 ]
  if ii == 1 :
    ii = 2
    context.bot.send_message( chat_id=chat.id, text = \
      "Ты моя буся сладкая. Поиграем в зеркало, ты мне что-то напиши, а я это переверну" )
  else :
    context.bot.send_message( chat_id=chat.id, text = text2 )

print( "Бот запущен. Нажмите Ctrl+C для завершения" )
token = ''
updater = Updater( token, use_context = True )
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler( CommandHandler( "start", on_start ) )
dispatcher.add_handler( MessageHandler( Filters.all, on_message ) )
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять комментарии к коду - что вы поменяли, почему ваш код работает, а код из вопроса не работает. В смысле - не только в самом коде комментарии (хотя это и хорошо, но их там сложно искать), но и до кода напишите пояснение.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, я исправил !

Comment: Отличное пояснение )

Comment: @CrazyElf я кстати проверил - работает !