# Как узнать остановлен ли телеграм бот пользователем?

Tags: python, telebot, бот, telegram

Мне необходимо узнать, что пользователь активировал бота **/start**. Это не проблема, но проблема, если пользователь остановил его позже.

Мне необходимо *сделать проверку*, что **бот может писать** пользователю.
Конечно, можно проверить это отправив сообщение, но это костыли. Если ли лёгкий способ узнать это?

Comment: я один раз писал бота ```https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343538/Почему-появляется-ошибка-если-отправлять-боту-эмодзи``` но у меня там не было возможности остановить бота. Бот запускался у меня локально на моём компе с помощью команды ```python имя_бота.py``` и он работал до тех пор, пока я не закрою консоль или перезагружу компьютер. Даже не знаю, может ли сам пользователь остановить бота, это же ваш бот

Comment: Под "остановить бота" я подразумеваю, когда пользователь блокирует его.

Comment: а, ну понятно, надо проверить, заблокирован ли ваш бот. Нет, я не знаю, как это сделать )))